# Javascript JSON YouTube API viewCount isn't working

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, youtube

I need to get the views of a video with JavaScript (Chrome Extension), but i don't get it to work.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/H542nLTTbu0?alt=json',function(data) { 
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
                var numViews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
            });
    });
});
```

But if I try to get them, the error message it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entry' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "feed" property in the JSON file you are downloading -- I'd recommend to use some tool (like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to investigate the JSON structure, and edit the code based on what property you need.

EDIT: Looks like the value you need is stored in `data.entry.yt$statistics.viewCount`. No need for `each`...

EDIT2:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/H542nLTTbu0?alt=json',function(data) { 
            var numViews = +data.entry.yt$statistics.viewCount;
            // + converts the string to int
    });
});
```

Comment: How do i have to write this part without "each"?: var numViews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];

Comment: Oh. Got it. Big thanks! Working since yesterday on it.. was so frustrating. Thank you :)

Comment: Here you go. I wrote it for you. I am nice :-)